# How to download files from Firebase storage In NextJs13

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, next.js13

I am building a website that distributes eBooks using NextJs and Firebase. I want to download a pdf file from the cloud firestrore when the user clicks on the download button

I tried to download the file like this

```
const fetchFile = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(getDownloadURL(fileRef));
  console.log(response)
  const blob = await response.blob();
  return blob;
};
const download = async () => {
  const blob = await fetchFile();
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'file.pdf');
};
```

A file is downloaded in my computer but when I try to open it i get an error saying failed to load document.
Right after i click the error button I get an error on the console saying:

> page.js:22     GET http://localhost:3000/[object%20Promise] 404 (Not Found)

After I logged the response to the console I found that it was returning http://localhost:3000/[object%20Promise] instead of the URL to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getDownloadURL` is an asynchronous method, that returns a `Promise`.
You'll need to `await` that call too.

So:

```
const fetchFile = async () => {
  const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(fileRef);
  const response = await fetch(downloadURL);
  console.log(response)
  const blob = await response.blob();
  return blob;
};
```